# Migrating security_level=3 addresses to Chrysalis (at given index)

Tags: python, chrysalis, migration

A couple of years ago I used the Iota Python SDK in order to generate some addresses.

```
api =  Iota(uri, seed)
api_response = api.get_new_addresses(index=index, count=30, security_level=3)
```

From there I chose one at a specific index, let's say `25`, to which I transferred a certain amount from an exchange.

While now trying to migrate that wallet over to Chrysalis, after entering the seed in the Firefly app, it tells me that it can't find the balance.

I have two suspects for this cause:

- A non-zero index (maybe the app only checks the first address for the
  seed), or
- the higher `security_level`. I think `security_level=2`
  would be the default.

I think the non-zero index shouldn't really be an issue, but it may be, because the app is telling me pretty fast that the seed is incorrect, and I think it would take some more time to come up with the address at index 25.

How do I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am bundling the information I have seen on Discord:

> Firefly only supports security level 2, so you have to send the funds
> to an address with security level 2 first and then do the migration
> with Firefly or you generate a migration address yourself and send the
> funds directly to it with whatever you used until now Or you compile
> Firefly yourself with security level 3

> The migration address has no security level I mean a normal address to
> which you transfer your funds before the actual migration

Q: Ak, ok I thought security_level 2 was the default. A "normal" address

> Yes that's the default for the wallets With the python lib you can
> generate a chrysalis address, but then you still need to convert it to
> a migration address and send it there, which is not possible with the
> new lib